# pod install returns error "Web Page Blocked"

Tags: ios, cocoapods

When running `pod install --repo-update` on my build server, I am getting the following error:

`JSON::ParserError - 784: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><style type="text/css">html,body{height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}.oc{display:table;width:100%;height:100%;}.ic{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;height:100%;}div.msg{display:block;border:1px solid #30c;padding:0;width:500px;font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;margin:10px auto;}h1{font-weight:bold;color:#fff;font-size:14px;margin:0;padding:2px;text-align:center;background: #30c;}p{font-size:12px;margin:15px auto;width:75%;font-family:helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:left;}</style><title>Web Page Blocked</title></head><body><div class="oc"><div class="ic"><div class="msg"><h1>Web Page Blocked</h1><p>An error occurred while trying to rate the website using the webfiltering service. <br /><br />Web filter service error: rating timeout
<br/>User name: guest
<br/>Group name: SSO_Guest_Users</p></div></div></div></body></html>`

It must be calling some website or web service, but I don't know which one or where it's failing. The HTML page that is returned looks like this:

[image]

My build was working fine as of 5 days ago, and I don't know what changed or how to troubleshoot this.

**EDIT**

I narrowed the problem down to these 2 pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.14.0'
pod 'SwiftJWT'
```

I have seven other pods which do not fail.

Comment: This looks like an issue on your network; some form of web filtering product has been implemented and it isn't working. Contact your network administrators

Answer (score 1):

I narrowed the problem down to 2 pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.14.0'
pod 'SwiftJWT'
```

I resolved the first issue by changing to the latest Firebase/Core:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.17.0'
```

My *guess* is that Google must have removed versions lower than 6.0 from Cocoapods within the last several days.

I could not resolve the second issue using Cocoapods, so I switched to using Swift Package Manager for this package:

```
https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Swift-JWT.git
```

After this, I was able to build on the server again!

**EDIT** My coworker experienced the same issue and resolved it by running this command:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/
```

I recall that at some point in my troubleshooting I ran the same command on the build server.

My speculation is that the "Web Page Blocked" issue was caused by our company's Fortinet firewall, resulting in corruption of Cocoapods, and then the only way to fix it was to clear Cocoapods repos and start over. I'm sorry for such a confusing answer, I'm not certain I know exactly what fixed it, but perhaps this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: I just verified that Firebase 5.14.0 is still installable. If the problem persists, please file an issue including the Podfile at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues